# capturing words between double quotes in awk

Tags: regex, linux, awk

I'm trying to print the name of my Linux distribution. The output of `cat /etc/os-release` for my distro is:

```
NAME="Arch Linux"
PRETTY_NAME="Arch Linux"
ID=arch
BUILD_ID=rolling
ANSI_COLOR="0;36"
HOME_URL="https://www.archlinux.org/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://wiki.archlinux.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://bbs.archlinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.archlinux.org/"
LOGO=archlinux
```

Now I want to grab the `Arch Linux` from the second line. I used this command:

```
cat /etc/os-release | awk '/PRETTY_NAME=\".+\"/ {print $1}'
```

But this prints `PRETTY_NAME="Arch`

How can I grab the words (including space) from this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the field delimiter to double quotes `-F'"'` to remove quotes from output.

```
 awk -F'"' '/^PRETTY_NAME=/{print $2}' /etc/os-release
```

Comment: This includes the double quotes, but I guess I could pipe it to `tr -d '"'`. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, or change the awk field delimiter to "

Comment: You'll want to lose the [useless `cat`](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) too.

Comment: You don't need `tr`, Awk can do that with `gsub("\"","")`

Comment: `/^PRETTY_NAME=/{print $2}` or similar would be more robust.